# Pandas dataframe: vector function for the next row with column value lower than a specified row?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have OHLC price data in a Pandas Dataframe with datetime index and am back-testing trade entry signals.

One of them is to mark a buy entry pattern where a prior significant low was broken. I have written code below that works correctly, but I would like to vectorize it to return a vector function for the "FooBuy" column, if at all possible.

<strike>I am planning to use this code eventually in a live system, so having a vector that automatically responds to changing data would be a big benefit.</strike>

Can anyone suggest anything?

```
class FooBuy(PricePattern):

  def df_apply(self, df):

    if not ("SigLow" in df.columns):
       df["SigLow"] = SigLow().df_apply(df)  # correct pattern

    df["SigLowBrokenAt"] = None
    df["FooBuy"] = False

    for date, row in df[df.SigLow].iterrows():
        df_sorted_lows = df[date:].sort("Low", ascending=False)
        df_later_and_lower = df_sorted_lows[df_sorted_lows.Low < row["Low"]]
        if len(df_later_and_lower) > 0:
           df["SigLowBrokenAt"].ix[date] = df_later_and_lower.ix[0].name

    for date in df.SigLowBrokenAt.dropna():
        df["FooBuy"].ix[date] = True
```

Here's the code for SigLow:

```
class PricePattern(object):

  def __init__(self, shift=0, **kwargs):
    self.shift = shift

  def __repr__(self):
    return "{0}({1})".format(self.__class__.__name__, "" if self.shift == 0 else "shift=\"{0}\"".format(self.shift))

  def df_apply(self, df):
    raise NotImplementedError()


class SigLow(PricePattern):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(SigLow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def df_apply(self, df):
    return (df.Low.shift(self.shift) < df.Low.shift(self.shift + 1)) & \
        (df.Low.shift(self.shift) < df.Low.shift(self.shift - 1))
```

Here's some test code that passes:

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
  def _create_df(self, data):
    return 1 + pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'],
                            index=pd.date_range('2/25/2013 06:00', periods=len(data),
                                                freq='H')) / 100

  def _assert_true_alone(self, series, index):
    for i in arange(len(series)):
        self.assertTrue(series[i] or (i not in index))

  def _assert_all_false(self, series):
    for i in arange(len(series)):
        self.assertFalse(series[i])


class TestFooBuy(TestBase):

  def test_matches(self):
    data1 = [[48, 49, 34, 48],
             [48, 50, 46, 48],
             [47, 49, 38, 48],  # SL
             [48, 59, 48, 58],
             [57, 57, 50, 54],
             [53, 53, 36, 40],  # FB
             [39, 39, 29, 32]]

    df = self._create_df(data1)
    #df["FooBuy"] = FooBuy().df_apply(df)  # correct pattern
    FooBuy().df_apply(df)
    self._assert_true_alone(df.SigLow, [2])
    self._assert_true_alone(df.FooBuy, [5])

  def test_does_not_match(self):
    data1 = [[48, 49, 34, 48],
             [48, 50, 46, 48],
             [47, 49, 38, 48],  # SL
             [48, 59, 48, 58],
             [57, 57, 42, 48],  # SL
             [48, 50, 43, 44],
             [45, 52, 45, 51]]

    df = self._create_df(data1)
    #df["FooBuy"] = FooBuy().df_apply(df, config_defaults)  # correct pattern
    FooBuy().df_apply(df, config_defaults)
    #print df
    self._assert_true_alone(df.SigLow, [2, 4])
    self._assert_all_false(df.FooBuy)
```

Comment: Could you post sample data, even if it's fake.  It would be easy for an answerer to mock up some OHLC data, but when you post the data you can also post your expected result.  Also post the `defaults` column.

Comment: Done. I have removed `defaults` to make things simpler, as it's not relevant in this case.

Comment: Further update - I figured out how to conform to the pattern I wanted. Pretty simple really - just made a copy of the dataframe and then did my workings on that, returning just the series with the result in it. 

I suspect with all the iteration that it may still be quite slow with large datasets though, so if anyone does have any suggestions for how to remove the recursion/turn it into a pure vector, then please shout :)